# Adding A Title Every Time A number Changes

Tags: php, html, smarty

Hay everyone need abit of help because i'm new to coding.

Is it possible to add a title every time a number changes for example.

On my shows page there is episode block that shows what seasons and episodes are available and they are based out like this

```
Season 1. Episode 1
Season 1. Episode 2
Season 1. Episode 3
Season 2. Episode 1
Season 2. Episode 2
Season 2. Episode 3
```

What i want to do is every time the season number changes to add a title stating what season it is for example

**Season 1**

```
Season 1. Episode 1
Season 1. Episode 2
Season 1. Episode 3
```

**Season 2**

```
Season 2. Episode 1
Season 2. Episode 2
Season 2. Episode 3
```

Could anyone help me achieve this here is my code.

```
        <ul class="col2">
        {foreach from=$episodes key=id item=val name=episode_loop}
        <li>
                <h5 class="episode_item">
                    {if $global_settings.seo_links}
                        <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}</a>
                    {else}
                        <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}</a>
                    {/if}
                </h5>
        </li>
            {if $smarty.foreach.episode_loop.iteration % 4 eq 0}<div class="clear"></div>{/if}
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
```

Please someone help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how to do it with this template engine, but with regular PHP you could do something like

```
$currentSeason = 0;
foreach( $episodes as $key => $val )
{
    if( $val['season'] != $currentSeason )
    {
        .. Show Title ....
        $currentSeason = $val['season'];
    }

    ... Show rest of information ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Store the current season, and every time it changes output the header. I don't know what your data is like so you will likely have to adjust the check and printout but this should get you there (lines 3-6).

```
<ul class="col2">
    {foreach from=$episodes key=id item=val name=episode_loop}
        {if $currentSeason != $val.season}
            PUT YOUR SEASON TITLE HERE
            {$currentSeason=$val.season}
        {/if}
        <li>
            <h5 class="episode_item">
                {if $global_settings.seo_links}
                    <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}</a>
                {else}
                    <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}</a>
                {/if}
            </h5>
        </li>
        {if $smarty.foreach.episode_loop.iteration % 4 eq 0}<div class="clear"></div>{/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but they didn't work but i solved it be adding this

```
{if $val.episode eq 1}
   <h2>Season {$val.season}</h2>
        {/if}
            <li>
                <h5 class="episode_item">
                    {if $global_settings.seo_links}
                        <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.show}/{$val.perma}/season/{$val.season}/episode/{$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">Episode {$val.episode}{if $val.episodetitle} <span class="tv_episode_name"> - {$val.episodetitle}</span>{/if}</a>
                    {else}
                        <a class="link" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=episode&perma={$val.perma}&season={$val.season}&episode={$val.episode}" title="{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}">{$lang.show_episode_title|replace:'#season#':$val.season|replace:'#episode#':$val.episode}</a>
                    {/if}
                </h5>
        </li>
```